# C linked list - head is always NULL

Tags: c, list, pointers, scope

I want to implement a simple linked list in C. However I only have access to the list element locally, inside the list_append function, but not inside the main-function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_element {
    struct list_element *next;
    int val;
} list_element_t;

typedef struct list {
    struct list_element *first;
} list_t;


int list_append(list_t *list, int value) {
    if (list->first == NULL) { // if case 1
        // This scope is accessed after each list_append-call. I'm expecting it to be accessed only once.
        list = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));
        list_element_t *new_ele = (list_element_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_element_t));
        new_ele->next = NULL;
        new_ele->val = value;
        list->first = new_ele;

        printf("list first\n");
        printf("%d\n", list->first->val);
        return value;
    } else {
        printf("Do nothing.\n");
    }


    return -1;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    list_t list;
    list.first = NULL;

    printf("insert 47: %d\n", list_append(&list, 47));
    printf("insert 11: %d\n", list_append(&list, 11));
    printf("%d\n", list.first->val); // This will cause a seg fault.
}
```

I was expecting the if case 1 is only accessed in the first list_append call, but it's also accessed in the 2nd call (and any further calls).

Comment: What are you trying to do with `list = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));`? That line doesn't make sense (and should probably just be removed)

Comment: `list = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));` is modifying `list` inside the function, but has no effect outside. This means that the original `list` pointer you passed to `list_append` is discarded. Therefore the function will not update the  `list_t list` object passed into it.

Comment: Thanks, that already fixed the issue. I didn't realize that the memory for list was already allocated in the main function.

Comment: If it wasn't allocated in `main` then you would not be able to update the memory for the parameter. Any change you apply to `list` inside your function will never be visible after leaving it.

Comment: But list is a pointer. Why is that statement true for a pointer?

Comment: If you modify what `list` points to, it can be visible outside. But changing `list` itself will not. Theoretically you could pass a `list_t **` in order to modify the pointer itself (not needed in this case as already noted).

Comment: Changes to `*list` are visible outside of the function. Given that `list` is the same as passed by the caller. Changes to `list` on the other hand only affect the local copy. After that is changed, also changes to `*list` are no longer visible outside of that function because the caller does not know wher your copy of `list` now points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will address the problem from a slightly different perspective. Let's look at these lines one by one:

```
int list_append(list_t *list, int value) {
```

So far, we know that `list` is a pointer. It may point at something or it may be `NULL`. Chances are, it does point at something at least sometimes, otherwise it wouldn't make much sense to pass it to a function! The object is a list.

```
if (list->first == NULL)
```

Now it is possible to say that `list` definitely points at something, otherwise `list->first` wouldn't have much sense. One can only use `->` with pointers that do points at objects.

```
    list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
```

This line makes `list` forget what it is pointing at, and make it point at a brand new thing (here, a `list_t` object just returned by `malloc`).

It's great when a pointer can be made to point at a new objects. But what about the old object? Where does it go? Is there some other pointer still pointing at it? If so, what are we going to do with two lists? If not, there is a *memory leak*. Maybe it is not needed anymore? If so, it should be *freed* before the last pointer that points at it ceases to do so. The objects pointed to by pointers *inside* the objects that is going to be freed should also be considered the same way. Are *those* objects still needed? are there other pointers pointing at them? etc etc.

These are questions that are genuinely hard to answer. *You should not write code that begets difficult questions*.

Compare this to the correct code:

```
int list_append(list_t *list, int value) {
    if (list->first == NULL) { 
        list->first = malloc(sizeof(list_element_t));
```

Should you worry about the object that `list->first` is pointing at? *No, there is no such object*. That pointer is `NULL`! So if you have checked a pointer for `NULL`, you can freely assign to that pointer.

Another situation where you should not worry about the old object is when you declare the pointer locally.

```
list_element_t* element = other_element;
```

Here too, there is no old object pointed-to by `element` before it is initialised.

*Every single time* you assign to a pointer, you should stop and ask yourself these questions. Is there an object that this pointer is pointing at before the assignment? If so, where does this object go? Do other pointers take care of it, or it is lost forever?

There are cases where you do need to answer these questions, for example, when traversing a linked list:

```
while (current != NULL) { 
    // do something
    current = current->next;
```

Here `current` definitely points at an object. Will that object be lost? Is there something else that points at that object? YES! It's a pointer in the previous node in the list (or the list itself, if `current` is a head). And the list with all its nodes is not going anywhere. So that object is not going to be lost, it is safe to assign `current`.

Of course, if you do assign something to a function parameter, you should know that the new value is only seen inside the function. But this is quite a different story.

Answer (score 2):

Your `list_append` function doesn't do what you think it does.

> ```
> int list_append(list_t *list, int value) {
>    if (list->first == NULL) { // if case 1
>        // This scope is accessed after each list_append-call. I'm expecting it to be accessed only once.
>        list = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));
>        list_element_t *new_ele = (list_element_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_element_t));
>        new_ele->next = NULL;
>        new_ele->val = value;
>        list->first = new_ele;
>
>        printf("list first\n");
>        printf("%d\n", list->first->val);
>        return value;
>    }
> ```

The `list` parameter is local to the function. You've modified that, but you have not modified the list it *points* to. When the function exits, that list is unchanged.

You may have meant to do something like:

```
int list_append(list_t *list, int value) {
    if (list->first == NULL) { 
        list->first = malloc(sizeof(list_element_t));
        ...
```

`list->first` being equivalent to `(*list).first` where the dereference of the `list` pointer is more apparent.